# Handling Data in Code First With Sequelize.js and Postgres

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, code-first

I created a new Postgres database and I began to fill the tables with data.
The tables got different relationship between each another.
I am using a node.js app and sequelize to handle the code first migration.

My problem is that I not so sure how should I handle the data itself in a code first approach.

Each migration script contains something simple like this :

up - creates a table,
down - drops the table ( and all the data inside of it )

What i am wondering about is how should I handle all the data which being added overtime to the different tables?

At present if I ever decide to run 'db:migrate:undo' on any of the scripts it will drop the table and all the data inside of it.

I would have liked to have full support in data restoration as well, so if I ever need to go as far as doing 'db:migrate:undo:all', once i run 'db:migrate' again I will have all the previous data restored.

Is there a nice approach to achieving that? or maybe it is a bad practice?

edit: 
sample file in the present-

```
module.exports = {
    up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) =>
      queryInterface.createTable('LookupType', {
        id: {
          allowNull: false,
          primaryKey: true,
          type: Sequelize.UUID,
        },
        name: {
          type: Sequelize.STRING(32),
          allowNull: false,
        },
        createdAt: {
          allowNull: false,
          type: Sequelize.DATE,
        },
        updatedAt: {
          allowNull: false,
          type: Sequelize.DATE,
        },
      },      
      {
        schema: 'lov'
      }),
    down: (queryInterface /* , Sequelize */) =>
      queryInterface.dropTable(
        {
          tableName: 'LookupType',
          schema: 'lov'
        }),
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Migrations are really just about managing and versioning *schema*, particularly during development and deployment stages.

In development you might have test data you can seed a database with and happily throw away during a migration rollback, but this could be disastrous on a production system.

My view is that once you've run that migration in production there's no going back unless absolutely necessary, and in that case you'll need another process to backup and recover your data.